# Positive measure of Lebesgue measure subset of R^2 has a non-measurable subset.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am stuck on the explanation for lemma2 in this thread [Lebesgue Measurable Subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942285/lebesgue-measurable-subset-of-0-1-times0-1?rq=1).
I tried to graph what he mentioned about 'pushed out', but I couldn't get the same conclusion, i.e,$E_{r}=[1-p,1]\times[1-q,1] $.

Any help would be appreciated it!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I couldn't figure out Lemma 2 in that thread.

Comment: I doubt his reasoning in the link that I attached because the negation of 'exist $x,y \in E$, with $x \neq y$, such that $x-y \in Q \times Q$' should be ' every $x,y \in E$, $x = y $ and $x-y \notin Q \times Q.$'

Answer (score 0):

So, he is just telling this: clearly $\mu(E+r)=\mu(E)$. But now, $E+r$ can be seen as the disjoint union of $E_r$ and $X:=(E+r)\setminus [0,1]\times[0,1]$. So you have that
$$\mu(E+r)=\mu(E_r)+\mu(X).$$

But now, clearly since $E\subseteq [0,1]\times[0,1]$, your set $X$ is a subset of $([0,1]\times[0,1] + r)\setminus [0,1]\times[0,1]$. And this set is just the set of couples $(x,y)$ with $1\le x\le 1+p$ and $1\le y\le 1+q$ , which has Lebesgue measure of $pq$. So $\mu(X)\le pq$ and you have your thesis.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. But still confused about his square [1-p,1][1-q,1], what does it means to say pushed out?

Comment: Yeah it means what I said, written in a non-precise way: the square $[1-p,1]\times[1-q,1]$, if you translate it by $+r$, becomes a subset of the complementary to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. His word confused me a lot, but your explanation is really nice. I understood what he wanted to do rn, It's basically the same you said above in a different way. ' pushed out '

Comment: Also, I just noticed that. Shouldn't $p,q \in Q\cap[0,1]$?